# How to handle a Web Designer with a too wide screen?

Tags: css, interface, screen-resolution

I keep receiving 2000x1500 web design (images to turn to actual website).
My screen resolution is at 1280x1024.

The web site look real bad on my monitor (everything seems way too big).

Right now I'm handling the main-background with background-size, I position/size some stuff with %, but it's not quite enough and it turns really complicated to handle (doesn't scale well either).

Is it possible to handle every single object to make their size relative to the screen size?
Kinda like a "zoom function", but for the html+css handling...

Comment: 2000px by 1500px has the same ratio of 1280x960 and 1024x768. If your designer thinks the design is correct (please forgive my obvious question) doesn't he want you to just downscale it before developing? This has happened to me some times, usually when receiving material from print designers, used to work on much larger files.

Comment: Could have, but no. Simply way to tell : I'd have to set the font size of around 4px. :)

Comment: Well, then. I've i've also been in that situation where the design my client wanted was simply horrible. I handled it by documenting in a nice email that they were refusing my proposals to reconsider, developing pixel-perfect with the design received and making sure they paid me before the final delivery. I didn't sign it, nor use it in my portfolio. But didn't lose a client. 

As for zoom-handling, you can either go with (yuck) flash, or use such a ridiculous amount of jquery to do it that your project would render impracticable.

Good luck there! :)

Comment: Well, that's pretty much what I wanted to confirm (the last part about JS / flash). Thanks. If you turned this to an answer, it's the one I'd accept.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the Google Analytics data for your users over the last month or too. Tidy data. Show designer graph, explain which resolutions your users have and ask them to design smaller pages!

If you don't have data, here is a bar chart showing % of traffic with different screen sizes for the last 3 months in the US to all sites running stat counter.

http://gs.statcounter.com/#resolution-US-monthly-201107-201109-bar

Ideally you'd design for a range of different sizes. One choice would be:

- 300px wide – For mobile devices with web browsers
- 748px wide – Which caters for medium sized devices as well as the iPad in portrait mode
- 978px wide – Roughly the most popular size for websites and the iPad in landscape mode.
- 1218px wide – For standard sized laptops
- 1378px wide – For large monitors

(sizes from http://www.logic52.com/2011/02/13/responsive-web-design-with-the-978-grid-system/)

Comment: If you meant to ask the designer to use common sense, already tried. Also, shouldn't a website handle gracefully different resolutions, maybe not -now- but eventually?

Comment: Yes, but if your designer is designing websites that are bigger than most peoples screens, then he is doing a bad job. Same as if a car designer designed wheels that were 100" across... Engineering wouldn't be expected to scale it all down...

Comment: Ideally, your designer would design for 3-4 different sizes – often targeting mobile, iPad/1024x786, 1280 and HD. Just designing for the absolute biggest size screen you can buy is not what their role is in this process.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Responsive Webdesign. Basically you design for various ranges of resolutions.
http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/ 
and
http://www.abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design

If you only design for the web and are not interested in delivering different experiences to visitors suited for their resolution, just stick to 960px width, don't accept weird formats from designers and spend hours fixing their thing into a usable design.